Ubuntu 24.04 - Bluetooth turned itself off and won't turn back on
Yesterday, Bluetooth was working on my desktop and, today, it isn't.  I know it was working because my keyboard uses Bluetooth.
There seems to be lots of Bluetooth issues but I haven't found one exactly the same.  In my case, when I open Settings > Bluetooth it says 'Bluetooth Turned Off'.  I click the button in the menu bar and it slides to the right and then immediately (and far quicker) slides back to the left.
I'm still new to linux.  I found these commands on other tickets.
The dot before 'bluetooth.service', below, is green and larger in Terminal.
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-12-16 17:48:38 GMT; 1h 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 914 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18400)
     Memory: 3.0M (peak: 3.5M)
        CPU: 37ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─914 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: Starting SDP server
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 bluetoothd[914]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Dec 16 17:48:38 pn50 systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.

rfkill shows this (I've excluded the WiFi section, which was also no, no):
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

bluetoothctl shows nothing:
$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#

lsmod shows:
$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1028096  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth

dmesg shows:
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    2.320549] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.320573] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.320574] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.320577] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.320579] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.320582] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.418354] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
[    4.418361] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    5.424876] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.424884] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.424890] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

hcitool doesn't list anything:
$ hcitool dev 
Devices:

/var/lib/bluetooth contains:
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/bluetooth 
total 4
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Dec 11 18:46 78:2B:46:B5:31:86

UPDATE
This is now happening on every restart
I have a temporary solution:
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb

but it only fixes it until I shutdown.

The "Waiting to connect to bluetoothd" message from bluetoothctl suggests that the bluetooth daemon isn't running for some reason. What happens if you run sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service? If that doesn't work, post the output of sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service?
